# Solve this First Order Non-Linear Differential Equation: $y'+y^2=\cos{2x} $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Trying to solve this seemingly simple first order non-linear differential equation:

$$y'+y^2=\cos{2x} $$

Considered separation of variables and bernoulli methods but figured it's not applicable. Please I need a hint.

Comment: It's a Riccati differential equation ; see methods in (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation)

Comment: Oh great! Seen it. Have learnt one today. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y'+y^2=\cos(2x)$$
Change of function : $y=\frac{Y'}{Y} \quad\to\quad y'=\frac{Y''}{Y}-\frac{Y'^2}{Y^2}$
$$\frac{Y''}{Y}=\cos(2x)$$
The general solution involves the Mathieu functions : 
$$Y=c_1\text{MathieuC}(0,\frac{1}{2},x)+c_2\text{MatieuS}(0,\frac{1}{2},x)$$
$$y(x)=\frac{c_1 \frac{d}{dx} \text{MatieuC}(0,\frac{1}{2},x)+c_2\frac{d}{dx}\text{MatieuS}(0,\frac{1}{2},x)}{c_1\text{MatieuC}(0,\frac{1}{2},x)+c_2\text{MatieuS}(0,\frac{1}{2},x)}$$